# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - project does not contain UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am having a problem with testflight. I researched this error a little, but there is no code related to UIWebView anywhere in my application. I searched it in my project and I'm sharing the screenshot with you.

[image]

Additionally, I ran the grep -R UIWebView code in the terminal and got the output as follows.

grep -R UIWebView
Terminal output:
Binary file ./MyList.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/bbaran.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looking at the search results, GoogleSignIn clearly states that it is using UIWebView.

Comment: Yes, it is a changelog of the very old 2.0.0 version of GoogleSignIn spm. It is just a changelog should we take that into consideration?

Comment: Something (library/framework) your app is using must be using UIWebView.

Comment: But nothing like this appears in the search results.

Comment: If you run out of good ideas, I would try to make "smaller" builds that isolate or remove targets / modules / components, and see if you can get a build to pass TF's processing phase. There might also be a parsing problem, like you don't have it in code, but one of the included document files confuses TF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project had AFNetworking as xcframework and by removing the very old version (2.6.3) of AFNetworking for now, I solved my problem and was able to send packages to TF.